# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. Angular 2 Final release

Tags: angular

I am using the latest version of angular and following the quickstart from angular.io . I am getting this error. I tried all the fixes present on stack overflow but didn't worked out for me.I am using exactly same config files .
Below is my app.module.ts

```
----------
    import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
    import { routing,    appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';
    import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
    import {PageNotFoundComponent} from './pagenotfound.component';
    import { MileStoneModule }         from './milestone/milestone.module';
    import { RecepientModule }         from './recepient/routing.module';
    @NgModule({
        imports: [
    BrowserModule,      
    routing,
    MileStoneModule, RecepientModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule,ReactiveFormsModule,FormsModule
   // AlertModule,DatepickerModule,Ng2BootstrapModule

],
    declarations: [AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent

],
   providers: [
    appRoutingProviders
     ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
   export class AppModule { }
```

The Add component where I am using ReactiveFormModule is

```
 import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
 import { Router, ActivatedRoute }       from '@angular/router';
 import { MileStoneService } from './milestone.service';
 import { MileStoneModel } from './milestoneModel';
 import { FormBuilder, FormGroup  ,FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
 import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

 @Component(
     {
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl:'./milestoneadd.html'
    ,

    providers: [MileStoneService]


}
 )
 export class MileStoneAddComponent implements OnInit {
     newMileStone = new MileStoneModel();
     errorMessage: string;
     form : FormGroup;

constructor( private _service: MileStoneService) {


}

     ngOnInit() {

    // the long way
    this.form = new FormGroup({
    Id: new FormControl(),
    Name: new FormControl(),
    StartDate: new FormControl()
     });

     }


     private saveMileStone(mileStone: MileStoneModel) {
         this._service.addMileStone(mileStone).subscribe(
        milestones => this.newMileStone = milestones,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
     }

 }
```

The HTML code is below

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="md-col-8">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"> Add MileStone</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form  [formGroup]="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="md-col-4">
                        <label>  MileStone Name:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-col-4">
                        <input  formControlName="Name"  />
                        <input type="hidden" formControlName="Id" />
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="md-col-4"><label> StartDate</label></div>
                    <div class="md-col-4">

                        <input formControlName="StartDate"  />



                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group pull-right" role="group" aria-           label="...">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Cancel</button>
                    &nbsp;

            <button type="button"  (click)="saveMileStone(newMileStone)" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>

            {{ newMileStone|json }}
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
          </div>
```

The package.json file is below .

```
   {
     "name": "angular-quickstart",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
      "lite": "lite-server",
      "postinstall": "typings install",
      "tsc": "tsc",
      "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
      "typings": "typings"
                 },
          "license": "ISC",
          "dependencies": {
            "@angular/common": "~2.0.1",
            "@angular/compiler": "~2.0.1",
            "@angular/core": "~2.0.1",
            "@angular/forms": "~2.0.1",
            "@angular/http": "~2.0.1",
            "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.1",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.1",
            "@angular/router": "~3.0.1",
            "@angular/upgrade": "~2.0.1",
            "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.1",
            "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
            "core-js": "^2.4.1",
            "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
            "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
            "systemjs": "0.19.39",
            "zone.js": "^0.6.25",
            "jquery": "^3.1.1"
          },
          "devDependencies": {
            "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
            "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
            "typescript": "^2.0.3",
            "typings": "^1.4.0",
             "gulp": "^3.9.1",
            "q": "^1.4.1",
            "grunt": "1.0.1",
            "grunt-contrib-copy": "1.0.0",
            "grunt-contrib-uglify": "1.0.1",
            "grunt-contrib-watch": "1.0.0",
            "grunt-ts": "5.5.1"
          }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Which module is `MilestoneAddComponent` declared in. That module should have FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule in imports

Comment: Hi Siraj , Thanks for quick reply I was looking for the solution from 2 days .The error itself not says that I am missing the import on the sub module. I import FormModule and ReactiveFormsModule  in the main app.module.ts file and I was assuming that it will be available in all other components automatically but I need to do import on the submodule also .

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a shared module (I left out all the imports):

```
@NgModule({
      imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, MenubarModule, InputTextModule ], 
      declarations: [ ErrorMessagesComponent],
      exports: [ CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule, RouterModule,
                InputTextModule, ErrorMessagesComponentng  ] 
   })

   export class SharedModule {
      static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
      return {
         ngModule: SharedModule,
         providers: [ AuthorizationService ]
      };
   }
}
```

In the app.module.ts (notice the SharedModule.forRoot):

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes), SharedModule.forRoot(), 
               HomeModule ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    providers: [ appRoutingProviders ]
}) 

export class AppModule {}
```

To use it in another module:

```
import { SharedModule }   from '../shared/shared.module';
import {routing} from './home.routing'


@NgModule({
    imports: [ SharedModule, routing],
    declarations: [ HomeComponent, LoginComponent, RegisterComponent, VerifyComponent, 
                   VerifyEmailComponent, ForgotComponent, ForgotVerifyComponent, 
                   ChangeComponent, ChallengeComponent, LogoutComponent ], 
    bootstrap: [ HomeComponent ],
    providers: [ ]

}) 

export class HomeModule {}
```

Comment: Hi John this is done inside ngOnInit() {

       // the long way
         this.form = new FormGroup({
         Id: new FormControl(),
          Name: new FormControl(),
           StartDate: new FormControl()
          });

         }   Although the question was not about this one . The issues was I didnot import ReactiveFormModule in my SubModule where MileStoneAddConponenet was declared . As mentioned by #siraj in above comment.

Comment: @YashveerSingh please add this as an answer. I can't find a single line in the docs mentioning how to make imports of the root module available to all sub modules.

Comment: -snolflake the question is already answered by @Siraj . The problem with  my code was that I assumed that it will be the case and  which was the cause of the issue . I am not sure which answer  you are referring to.

Comment: @snolflake, I think I found something in the docs that addresses this: "Modules do not inherit access to the components, directives or pipes that are declared in other modules. What AppModule imports is irrelevant to [other modules] and vice versa."  See my answer for a reference link.

Comment: Thats what i said, you have to use the shared module concept

Comment: @MarkRajcok Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

See Angular Module FAQ:
[What does "Can't bind to 'x' since it isn't a known property of 'y'" mean?](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-why-cant-bind-to)
In your case, **this part** applies:

> This error usually means either that you neglected to declare the directive "x" or **you haven't imported the module to which "x" belongs**.

Also (and probably more helpful, based on your interaction with @Siraj), the [Angular Modules guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#add-the-_contactmodule_) mentions the following:

> Modules do not inherit access to the components, directives or pipes that are declared in other modules. What `AppModule` imports is irrelevant to [other modules] and vice versa.

You have two choices (pick one):

1. Create a shared module that [re-exports](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#re-exporting-other-modules) the `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormModule` (in the module's `exports` list). Then import this shared module in your sub/feature module (in the sub module's `imports` list).
   See @JohnBaird's answer for an example.
    What ModuleA *exports is* relevant to other modules, if they import ModuleA.
2. Add `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormModule` to your sub/feature module's `imports` list.